# I want to prevent the service from being onDestory at the end of the app

Tags: android, service, background, foreground

I am currently implementing a video call app. When I quit my app, service is not working. How can I keep the service alive..?
Please help me.

The mainActivity calling service and it was destoryed, passing parameter values to CallService.class.

That way, CallService.class will be called from the start method.

```
public static void start(Context context, QBUser qbUser, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {

    Log.i(TAG,"CallService start");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallService.class);

    intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_COMMAND_TO_SERVICE, Consts.COMMAND_LOGIN);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_QB_USER, qbUser);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT, pendingIntent);


    context.startService(intent);
}

public static void start(Context context, QBUser qbUser) {
    start(context, qbUser, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //챗 서비스 만들기
    createChatService();
    Log.d(TAG, " CallService onCreate()");
}

/** 서비스가 시작되면 이 메소드가 호출된다. **/
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CallService onStartCommand");

    //인텐트로 받아온 값들을 할당
    parseIntentExtras(intent);

    //적절한 액션으로 시작한다. (로그인이냐, 로그아웃이냐)
    startSuitableActions();

    //시스템에 의해 종료가 되어도 서비스는 물론, 전달되었던 intent 값까지 모두 유지시켜주는 값
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

private void parseIntentExtras(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
        currentCommand = intent.getIntExtra(Consts.EXTRA_COMMAND_TO_SERVICE, Consts.COMMAND_NOT_FOUND);
        pendingIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Consts.EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT);
        currentUser = (QBUser) intent.getSerializableExtra(Consts.EXTRA_QB_USER);
    }
}

private void startSuitableActions() {
    if (currentCommand == Consts.COMMAND_LOGIN) {
        Log.i(TAG,"CallService startSuitableActions");
        startLoginToChat();
    } else if (currentCommand == Consts.COMMAND_LOGOUT) {
        Log.i(TAG,"CallService Logout");
        logout();
    }
}

/** 채팅 서비스 생성하기 **/
private void createChatService() {
    if (chatService == null) {
        Log.i(TAG,"CallService createChatService");
        QBTcpConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new QBTcpConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setSocketTimeout(0);
        QBChatService.setConnectionFabric(new QBTcpChatConnectionFabric(configurationBuilder));

        QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true);
        chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
    }
}

/** 로그인 들어가기 전 **/
private void startLoginToChat() {
    if (!chatService.isLoggedIn()) {
        Log.i(TAG,"CallService startLoginToChat");
        loginToChat(currentUser);
} else {
    sendResultToActivity(true, null);
        Log.i(TAG,"CallService sendResultToActivity");
}
}

/** 로그인 **/
private void loginToChat(QBUser qbUser) {
    chatService.login(qbUser, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CallService loginToChat onSuccess");
            startActionsOnSuccessLogin();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CallService loginToChat onError " + e.getMessage());
            sendResultToActivity(false, e.getMessage() != null
                    ? e.getMessage()
                    : "Login error");
        }
    });
}

private void startActionsOnSuccessLogin() {
    initPingListener();
    initQBRTCClient();
    sendResultToActivity(true, null);
}

private void initPingListener() {
    ChatPingAlarmManager.onCreate(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "CallService initPingListenerPing");
    ChatPingAlarmManager.getInstanceFor().addPingListener(new PingFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void pingFailed() {
            Log.d(TAG, "CallService initPingListenerPing chat server failed");
        }
    });
}

private void initQBRTCClient() {
    rtcClient = QBRTCClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "CallService initQBRTCClient");
    // Add signalling manager
    chatService.getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager().addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
            if (!createdLocally) {
                rtcClient.addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
            }
        }
    });

    // Configure
    QBRTCConfig.setDebugEnabled(true);
    SettingsUtil.configRTCTimers(CallService.this);

    // Add service as callback to RTCClient
    rtcClient.addSessionCallbacksListener(WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this));
    rtcClient.prepareToProcessCalls();
}

private void sendResultToActivity(boolean isSuccess, String errorMessage) {
    if (pendingIntent != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CallService sendResultToActivity()");
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_LOGIN_RESULT, isSuccess);
            intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_LOGIN_ERROR_MESSAGE, errorMessage);

            pendingIntent.send(CallService.this, Consts.EXTRA_LOGIN_RESULT_CODE, intent);
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
            String errorMessageSendingResult = e.getMessage();
            Log.d(TAG, errorMessageSendingResult != null
                    ? errorMessageSendingResult
                    : "Error sending result to activity");
        }
    }
}

public static void logout(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_COMMAND_TO_SERVICE, Consts.COMMAND_LOGOUT);
    context.startService(intent);
}

private void logout() {
    destroyRtcClientAndChat();
}

private void destroyRtcClientAndChat() {
    if (rtcClient != null) {
        rtcClient.destroy();
    }
    ChatPingAlarmManager.onDestroy();
    if (chatService != null) {
        chatService.logout(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                chatService.destroy();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "logout onError " + e.getMessage());
                chatService.destroy();
            }
        });
    }

    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "CallService Service onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CallService Service onBind)");
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CallService Service onTaskRemoved()");
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    destroyRtcClientAndChat();
}
```

}

Comment: You need to create a onGoing Notification by `startForeground(notification)`

Comment: Where should I add it? startForeground(notification)?